# How to use nginx as reverse proxy to direct localhost:9292 to a sub domain foo.localhost/?

Tags: nginx

I've learned how to pass `localhost:9292` to `localhost/foo` with the following directive:

```
location /foo {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9292;
}
```

but I want do something like

```
foo.localhost -> localhost:9292
```

Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: With that you pass ´localhost/foo´ to ´localhost:9292´.

Comment: @gipi I want `foo.localhost` to `localhost:9292`

Comment: "I've learned how to pass localhost:9292 to localhost/foo with the following directive", to me seems the opposite, that directive is called from ´http://localhost/foo´ and internally calls  ´http://localhost:9292´.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If foo.localhost is your sub domain name and you want to proxy pass sub-domain to main-domain, you can use proxy_pass and you can learn a little more about `server` directive if needed. An example:

```
server {
  listem 8080;
  host sub.main.com;
  ...
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://main.com;
    break;
  }
}
server {
  listen 8081;
  host main.com;
  ...
  location / {
    //do something
  }
}
```

This is proxy pass, means when access sub.main.com, actually it finally dealt by main.com, but the client side still shows sub.main.com. If you want client side shows main.com, here should use redirect but not proxy_pass.